# PHP: Redis::subscribe hover has wrong information

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, redis, intelephense

**Setup**

1. PHP 8.2
2. Redis 5.3.7
3. VSCode 1.79.0
4. Intelephense 1.9.5

**Problem**

When using `Redis::subscribe` I get an error, because according to the hover `subscribe` only takes strings as parameters. But it should be `(array, callable)`. Not sure where the root of this bug lays. With redis, intelephense, vscode...?

[image]

On github in phpredis/redis.stub.php it says

```
/**
 * Subscribe to one or more Redis pubsub channels.
 *
 * @param array    $channels One or more channel names.
 * @param callable $cb       The callback PhpRedis will invoke when we receive a message
 *                           from one of the subscribed channels.
 *
 * @return bool True on success, false on faiilure.  Note that this command will block the
 *              client in a subscribe loop, waiting for messages to arrive.
 *
 * @see https://redis.io/commands/subscribe
 *
 * @example
 * $redis = new Redis(['host' => 'localhost']);
 *
 * $redis->subscribe(['channel-1', 'channel-2'], function ($redis, $channel, $message) {
 *     echo "[$channel]: $message\n";
 *
 *     // Unsubscribe from the message channel when we read 'quit'
 *     if ($message == 'quit') {
 *         echo "Unsubscribing from '$channel'\n";
 *         $redis->unsubscribe([$channel]);
 *     }
 * });
 *
 * // Once we read 'quit' from both channel-1 and channel-2 the subscribe loop will be
 * // broken and this command will execute.
 * echo "Subscribe loop ended\n";
 */
public function subscribe(array $channels, callable $cb): bool;
```